# Binding Linux cpu process on single nodes.?

Tags: shell

I would like to ask you regarding linux cpu binding 
1. i have 2 cpu in single server (2 node for one server)
2. want to bind all process on single cpu like(0,2,5,7,9)

Can any one reply me how can i do that in linux using shell scripting.

Thanks

HM Suthar

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [taskset](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/taskset1.html).

Comment: yes but doing some extra tunning on cpu socket level